# How to use a column of one table into another in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
History with(BU,KPI_Name,YTD,Actual,Deviation)
Codes with (KPI_Name, KPI_code)
```

Contents of KPI_Name column of **History table** is exactly copied into KPI_Name of **Codes table**. This KPI_Name value is a long statement for which i have developed a "Short Code" for understanding and copied into Codes table.

Now, in **History table** I want to use the KPI_Code column of **Codes table** instead of KPI_name column of History table.

So output should be: KPI_Table with (BU,KPI_Code,YTD,Actual,Deviation)

Hope I am able to make you understand what I am asking for.

I tried many codes but the problem is **Codes table** contains only 30 rows and the output of **History table** after execution contains 90 rows so it not mapping the codes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the issue is why does the **Codes** tables only contain 30 rows whereas **History** contains 90. You should just be able to look at the values in **Codes** to see which are missing.

Using SQL you could:

```
select h.KPI_Name, c.KPI_Code  
from History h  
left outer join Codes c on c.KPI_Name = h.KPI_Name
```

Once you've worked out what's wrong with the code conversion you can add a KPI_Code column to History using

```
alter table History add KPI_Code (data type)
```

Then populate it from Codes something like:

```
update History  
set KPI_Code = c.KPI_Code  
from History  
inner join Codes c on c.KPI_Name = History.KPI_Name
```

If you can't understand why the KPI_Code generation is not working, post that code

Comment: Thing is, History table is for 3 business unit. And all business unit contains same rows( name of all 30 rows are same for all bu) thats y i coded a small code. In code table, it just contain the code for each row. But in case of the History table after execution it is showing me the result dor all business units( treat business units as departments). Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data to explain the problem - inputs and required output

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select H.BU, C.KPI_Code, H.YTD, H.Actual, H.Deviation
from History H
inner join Codes C
on C.KPI_Name = H.KPI_Name
```

Comment: yeah i tried this but it was giving me 3 times of the actual rows. For example, for 30 rows it is giving me 90 rows as an output. May b becuz of inner join?